# Unable to focus Input element inside a Bootstrap Popover inside a jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-dialog, popover

I am having a difficult time getting this to work. I have a link that opens a jQuery UI Dialog which contains links. Those links open a Bootstrap popover which contain an input field. For some reason, the input field is not editable.

See: http://www.bootply.com/Z46ZXA133U

Markup :

```html
<div id="dialog">
  <a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-title="Login" data-container=".ui-front" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login">Login</a>
</div>
<form id="popover-content" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" value="try changing me">
</form>
```

Script :

```js
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
});
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true, 
    content: function() {
        return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
});
```

Comment: appears to be some layer and focus confusion between the modal dialog you have created and the popover that appears upon clicking "login."

Comment: I've checked the z-indices and they seem to be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you have

```css
data-container="body"
```

on your popover. At the same time, `ui-widget-overlay` and `ui-front` covers the body area entirely, preventing clicks and keyboard events from being "sent" from body to the popover.

Change to

```css
data-container=".ui-front"
```

and you are good. Forked bootply -> **http://www.bootply.com/AXpc6PKuSO**

Answer (score 1):

in my case change  data-container="body"  to .ui-front did not help!
But the direction is right
I get modal body container selector and use them!

container: '#myModal-2 > section > div.modal-dialog > div',

Try to explain: if you use container='body' and use modal then modal overlay is blocking focus on body elements

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by removing `tabindex="-1"` from the modal div